# make 'match 'is up to date

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I run the code of `siftDemoV4` I get the following  error:

> make 'match 'is up to date

What's wrong with this? I know that there is something wrong with the `Makefile`:

```
# ------------------ Compilation options ------------------------

# Loads math library.  
LIBS = -lm

# Flags for the C compiler:
#   -Wall for strict gcc warnings (requires prototypes for all functions).
#   -g to produce debug data for gdb
#   -O for optimization
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

CC = gcc

# --------------------- Code modules ----------------------------

# Object files
OBJ = match.o util.o

# Definitions
DEFS = defs.h

# ------------------------ Rules --------------------------------

match: ${OBJ}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJ} ${LIBS}

# Implicit rule used by Gnu Make: $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
${OBJ}: ${DEFS}
```

Comment: That's not an error - that's just information to tell you that `match` is already newer than its dependencies.  There's nothing to be done unless you edit (e.g.) `match.c`.  If you want to *force* a rebuild, regardless, then consider `make -B`.